# Bootstrap Thumbnail Slider/Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, image-gallery

How do I edit this Bootstrap thumbnail slider/carousel http://www.bootply.com/79859 so that it looks [like this one](http://www.listentoottawa.com/#gallery-1-section)? I want to get rid of the whitespace between the thumbnails and make the thumbnails scrollable (without a scrollbar).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the styling for the thumbnail list. Add a class selector `.thumbs` to the `<ul>` containing the thumbnails and the following CSS:

```
.thumbs > li {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/bnBRfcgacy).

As for making the thumbnails vertically scrollable there is a proof of concept [here](http://jsbin.com/vehedijevi/edit?html,css,output) which shows you how to use `overflow` to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! The CSS for the thumbs worked, but I'm still having trouble with the scrolling. I'm trying to achieve an effect like this: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/56/